# how to validate the date form in PHP using codeigniter

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I want to validate the date form when we have not select any date it should not to allow us by giving notification.Here is my code in "VIEWS"

```
<input name="date" class="i-s input-sm btn-sm btn-rounded datepicker-input form-control" type="text" value="From Date" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy" required/>
```

Comment: use CI form validation library for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should not set value, just use placeholder

```
<input name="date" class="i-s input-sm btn-sm btn-rounded datepicker-input form-control" type="text" placeholder="From Date" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy" required/>
```

Comment: if it's working can you upvote and select the correct answer

Comment: and i also included <?php echo validation_errors(); ?> below the <form> tag